# How to set two div relative?

Tags: html, stylesheet

How can I set two `div`s side by side so that by increasing the height of the second `div`   height of the first `div` increases simultaneously.

I have tried to make it like this:

```
#content6 > #product-left{
    width: 355px;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
}
#content6 > #product-left ul li a{
    font-size:12px;
}
#content6 > #divide{
    background: url('../images/nav-btn.jpg') repeat-y;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    width: 20px;
    position:absolute;
    /* position: fixed; */
    display: block;
    /* margin-left: 9px; */
    /*border: 1px solid;*/
}
#content6 > #content-right{
    float: left;
    width: 655px;
    height: 300px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    /*border: 1px solid;*/
}
```

Here is html page:

```
<div id="content6">
        <div id="product-left">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">PTFE COATED FIBERGLASS FABRICS</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">PTFE COATED FIBERGLASS FARBIC SELF-ADHESIVE</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">PTFE COATED FIBERGLASS BELTS</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">PTFE COATED FIBERGLASS OPEN MESH DRYER BELTS</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">SILICON RUBBER COATED FIBERGLASS FABRIC</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">HIGH TEMP FIBERGALSS WOVEN-NONWOVEN FILTER BAGS</a> 
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="divide">

        </div>
        <div id="content-right">

        </div>
    </div>
```

Please Do the needful.

Comment: Could you provide your HTML?

Comment: Now I have to increase content-right div and also want to increase the height of divide div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Display `#content6` as a table and it's children containers as table cells:

```
#content6{
    display:table;
}
#product-left{
    width: 355px;
    height: auto;
    display:table-cell;
    background:#EEE;
}
#divide{
    background: url('../images/nav-btn.jpg') repeat-y;
    height: auto;
    width: 20px;
    display: table-cell;
    background:#F00;
}
#content-right{
    width: 655px;
    height: 300px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background:#CCC;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BmFXJ/3/)

Note that since `id`s should be unique, the immediate descendant CSS selectors are redundant here.

Comment: increase content-right div and also want to increase the height of divide di

Comment: Apologies, missed that. Edit made.